# Python38 packages on Fedora 31 yum

Tags: fedora, python, yum

On CentOS 8, I can get a range of packages for python 3.8 via yum (see below), most importantly python38-devel.

However, on Fedora 31 none of these packages are available.

Is there a way to get these packages on Fedora 31, e.g. by adding a third-party repository (similar to the apt repository [https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa))?

On CentOS 8:

```
# yum repolist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:41 ago on Thu 26 Nov 2020 05:05:05 PM UTC.
repo id                          repo name                                                                  status
AppStream                        CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                       4,933
BaseOS                           CentOS-8 - Base                                                            1,673
*epel                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                             6,721
*epel-modular                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                         0
extras                           CentOS-8 - Extras                                                             30

# yum search python38-
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:45 ago on Thu 26 Nov 2020 05:05:05 PM UTC.
======================= Name Exactly Matched: python38 =======================
python38.x86_64 : Version 3.8 of the Python interpreter
python38.i686 : Version 3.8 of the Python interpreter
python38.x86_64 : Version 3.8 of the Python interpreter
============================================ Name Matched: python38- =============================================
python38-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python3 packages
python38-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python3 packages
python38-ply.noarch : Python Lex-Yacc
python38-six.noarch : Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
python38-libs.x86_64 : Python runtime libraries
python38-cffi.x86_64 : Foreign Function Interface for Python 3 to call C code
python38-idle.x86_64 : A basic graphical development environment for Python
python38-idna.noarch : Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)
python38-libs.x86_64 : Python runtime libraries
python38-lxml.x86_64 : XML processing library combining libxml2/libxslt with the ElementTree API
python38-pytz.noarch : World Timezone Definitions for Python
python38-test.x86_64 : The self-test suite for the main python3 package
python38-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files needed for Python development
python38-babel.noarch : Library for internationalizing Python applications
python38-debug.x86_64 : Debug version of the Python runtime
python38-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files needed for Python development
python38-numpy.x86_64 : A fast multidimensional array facility for Python
python38-scipy.x86_64 : Scientific Tools for Python
python38-wheel.noarch : Built-package format for Python
python38-Cython.x86_64 : Language for writing Python extension modules
python38-jinja2.noarch : General purpose template engine for python3
python38-psutil.x86_64 : A process and system utilities module for Python
python38-pyyaml.x86_64 : YAML parser and emitter for Python
python38-tkinter.x86_64 : A GUI toolkit for Python
python38-PyMySQL.noarch : Pure-Python MySQL client library
python38-chardet.noarch : Character encoding auto-detection in Python
python38-pysocks.noarch : A Python SOCKS client module
python38-tkinter.x86_64 : A GUI toolkit for Python
python38-urllib3.noarch : Python3 HTTP library with thread-safe connection pooling and file post
python38-mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
python38-psycopg2.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL database adapter for Python 3
python38-requests.noarch : HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings
python38-pip-wheel.noarch : The pip wheel
python38-numpy-doc.noarch : Documentation for numpy
python38-pip-wheel.noarch : The pip wheel
python38-pycparser.noarch : C parser and AST generator written in Python
python38-radicale3.noarch : Python module for Radicale
python38-setuptools.noarch : Easily build and distribute Python 3 packages
python38-asn1crypto.noarch : Fast Python ASN.1 parser and serializer
python38-markupsafe.x86_64 : Implements a XML/HTML/XHTML Markup safe string for Python 3
python38-numpy-f2py.x86_64 : f2py for numpy
python38-rpm-macros.noarch : RPM macros for building RPMs with Python 3.8
python38-setuptools.noarch : Easily build and distribute Python 3 packages
python38-wheel-wheel.noarch : The Python wheel module packaged as a wheel
python38-cryptography.x86_64 : PyCA's cryptography library
python38-psycopg2-doc.x86_64 : Documentation for psycopg python PostgreSQL database adapter
python38-psycopg2-tests.x86_64 : A testsuite for A PostgreSQL database adapter for Python 2
python38-setuptools-wheel.noarch : The setuptools wheel
python38-setuptools-wheel.noarch : The setuptools wheel
```

On Fedora 31:

```
# yum repolist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:38 ago on Thu 26 Nov 2020 05:10:27 PM UTC.
repo id                   repo name                                     status
*fedora                   Fedora 31 - x86_64                            56,255
*fedora-modular           Fedora Modular 31 - x86_64                       142
*updates                  Fedora 31 - x86_64 - Updates                  22,403
*updates-modular          Fedora Modular 31 - x86_64 - Updates             139

# yum search python38
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:40 ago on Thu 26 Nov 2020 05:10:27 PM UTC.
======================= Name Exactly Matched: python38 =======================
python38.x86_64 : Version 3.8 of the Python interpreter
python38.i686 : Version 3.8 of the Python interpreter
python38.x86_64 : Version 3.8 of the Python interpreter
```

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora, Python 3 packages other than the interpreter are prefixed `python3-`; thus `dnf install python3-devel`.

Fedora 31 uses Python 3.7. It has reached its end of life, so you should upgrade. Fedora 32 will give you Python 3.8, 33 will give you 3.9.

Comment: The point though is that I want to specify the python version, independant of distribution, I don't want ot use the default `python3-`.

Comment: for extra info, this is for use with: https://github.com/marvel-nccr/ansible-role-python

Comment: You shouldn’t expect any new development happening on Fedora 31, it is dead.  If you have specific requirements for python 3.8 on Fedora 32 or 33 ( or later ) then make packages that Require python = 3.8.